# Upper-case in complex expressions [XSLT 1.0]

Tags: xml, xslt

Found how to make an "upper-case" for a simple issue. But how correctly do this when it's supposed to be a part of a complex expression?

Here is 2 unsolved examples at the bottom.

**SOURCE:**

```
<document>
  <element-1 attr-1="some value">
    <element-2 attr-2="12345"/>
 </element-1>      
</document>
```

**XSLT-1**  (original expressions with one simple upper-case)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="document">
    <document A="{element-1/@attr-1}"
              B="{normalize-space(concat(element-1/@attr-1, ' ', 
              element-1/element-2/@attr-2))}">

          <xsl:attribute name="UPPERNAME-1"> <!--simple Xpath UP -->
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(element-1/@attr-1,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ')"/>
         </xsl:attribute>

    </document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<document A="some value" B="some value 12345" UPPERNAME-1="SOME VALUE" />
```

**DESIRED attribute expressions i'd like combine with "upper-case" effect to** [XSLT 1.0]

```
UPPERNAME-2 ="{element-1/@attr-1}{element-1/element-2/@attr-2}"
UPPERNAME-3 ="{normalize-space(concat(element-1/@attr-1, ' ', 
              element-1/element-2/@attr-2))}">
```

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamLt same thing you need to do which you did for @B

Comment: that's cool, simple and working.